# Sourcetree hanging when trying to retrieve or apply a stash

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I had my changes stashed while working on branch 1. Then I switched to branch 2 to work on something else. Then I switched back to branch 1 and wanted to re-apply my stashed changes. However, once I left-click on my stash, Sourcetree stops responding. Same thing happens when I right-click and then click "Apply stash...". Also same thing happens when I create a new branch and want to retrieve/apply my stash.

How else can I try retrieving my stashed changes?

Other stashes seem to work fine - it is just that one, which is big, because I changed many files.

Comment: did you try with good ol' git?

Comment: Until now I had no experience with "good ol' git" but using "git stash apply" helped. Now I can see some conflicts in Sourcetree. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with Sourcetree more than once, `git stash apply` has fixed it every time thus far. I'm assuming it's a bug in the tool.